# Subspace decomposition

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, decomposition, eigendecomposition, svd

While reading the paper "Perturbation analysis for subspace decomposition with applications in subspace-based algorithms" by **Zhengyuan Xu**, I came across the decomposition technique called Subspace decomposition, where the data matrix $X$ (noise free) is decomposed as:
Journal: https://sci-hub.st/10.1109/TSP.2002.804084

$$X = U_s \Lambda_s V_s^H + U_n \Lambda_n V_n^H$$

where $U_s$ and $V_s$ span the column spaces of $X$ and $X^H$ respectively, whereas $U_n$ and $V_n$ span their orthogonal spaces. $\Lambda_s$ and $\Lambda_n$ are corresponding singular values (or eigenvalues).

Could someone explain me this decomposition? I understand it is related to SVD, but I am not sure about the additive funtion here.

Comment: How can one read the paper, without paying IEEE for access? https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1041039

Comment: I am using my academic institution login, and it is accessible.

Comment: @Neuling we are eager to help, but not all of us have your academic institution login.

Comment: [journals are lame](https://sci-hub.st/10.1109/TSP.2002.804084)

Comment: Thank you @OverLordGoldDragon .. The Journal is linked in the previous comment.  I will include it also in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation in a block matrix form:

\begin{eqnarray}X &=& U_s \Lambda_s V_s^H + U_n \Lambda_n V_n^H \\
    &=& \left[ \begin{matrix} U_s & U_n\end{matrix} \right]
\left[ \begin{matrix} \Lambda_s & 0 \\ 0 & \Lambda_n\end{matrix} \right]
\left[ \begin{matrix} V_s^H \\ V_n^H\end{matrix} \right] \\
 &=& U_t \Lambda_t V_t^H
\end{eqnarray}

where $U_t$, $\Lambda_t$, $V_t$ represent the total/complete SVD decomposition of $X$.